# UWP VS2017 - Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: This Member 'Value' has more than one item, use the Items property

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently encountering this error during compile time, but this error didn't occur before.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\XamlCompiler\
Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(308,5): Xaml Internal Error error 
WMC9999: This Member 'Value' has more than one item, use the Items property
```

I checked the `.csproj` file, and `line 308` in `Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets`file but no luck.

My Target version: `Windows 10, version 1809(10.0; Build 17763)`

My Min version: `Windows 10 Fall Creators Update(10.0; 16299)`

Did anyone encounter this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the error is quite cryptic, this is in fact an error in one of your XAML files. You can find a similar issue [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94c746d5-d89d-4a82-88c1-25d0d6e32ff0/this-member-itemtemplate-has-more-than-one-item-use-the-items-property?forum=winappswithcsharp). So try to look through the XAML files you have edited recently and search for any characters which are out of place. Especially focus on elements which have a `Value` property as well as an `Items` property.

You should identify the bug by finding the right XAML - if the designer crashes and displays some cryptic error message as well - then this file is probably the culprit.

Comment: Yes thank you for pointing it out. A few of my `.xaml` view files did contain unnecessary characters. As for the `Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targetsfile` file, there was no need in modifying it since you need to go through the process of changing it's write permissions first. Thanks again Martin!

Comment: Glad it helped! It should be reported to VS team however, as the error message itself is really confusing :-D . Happy coding!